# Cannot find Clementine toolbar

Tags: autotools

I'm just starting to use Clementine and I can't find the toolbar. It doesn't show on-screen. How can I make it show itself?
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

In a command line window (within your GUI) (<kbd>Ctrl Alt T</kbd>) type (well, first type `man clementine`):

```
clementine --show-osd
```

Now, look in the list of icons to the left of the screen. It looks like an orange slice. Right Click on the icon, and you'll see a menu which includes "`Lock to Launcher`". Select that, and you'll have an icon in the bar on the left.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the version of clementine from the main ubuntu/xubuntu software app is best, then the config file of clementine

/.var/app/org.clementine_player.Clementine/config/Clementine/clementine.conf

has some configs which seem not to reset after exiting the program, that means if the main window is minimized it stays in the tray as icon with no way to maximize it. this config persists after removal of clementine. so i found out that under

```
[main window]
hidden=false
maximized=true
```

this needs to be set as above then clementine starts as normal